# Android: Is there a .TranslationX() change listener for a view

Tags: android, animation

I have a button in my layout. And I am animating the position of that button using ObjectAnimator with translationX animation.

```
ObjectAnimator btnAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myBtn, "translationX", 
        ViewHelper.getTranslationX(myBtn), 0);

btnAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
        Log.i("TAG","Animation Finished");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator arg0) {}

    @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator arg0) {}
});
btnAnimator.setDuration(animationSpeed).start();
```

Now I would like to have a listener for the TranslationX of that button to notify whenever the TranslationX position of the button changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

1) Override [onLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout(boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) in your view to manually compare and detect position changes.

2) Use onLayoutChangeListener on your View:

```
button.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft,
                    int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        // Check your new position vs the old one
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have already tried the `addOnLayoutChangeListener` but its returning the position only at the starting and ending of the button movement, but not while moving.

Comment: Then try onLayout() :)

Comment: I wonder why there is no Listener for TranslationX directly. I can do onLayout() but now I have to create a separate class and extend the view.

Comment: Because also during animation you may implement your own interpolator, which will give you the desired values, and update on its current state.
I think there was no need for an additional listener, if you can easily override onLayout();

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would go for onLayout().

Comment: onLayout is not invoked when translationX is changed

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question as `translationX` is not related to the view layout, therefore the methods `onLayout` and `onLayoutChange` won't be called on translation changes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy way I found to do what you're after:

```
btnAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        Log.e("TAG", "translateX: "+animation.getAnimatedValue("translationX"));
    }
});

btnAnimator.setDuration(animationSpeed).start();
```

Comment: Yeah. Bunch of Thanks. Its working as desired. Though I am looking for a listener in situations other than animating the button, this works perfectly for me.

Comment: But would this work for other types of animations performed onto views? What about Animators set on LayoutTransition objects?

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it worked as a decent way of listening for changes of the view translation.

```
var previousTranslationX = view.translationX
var previousTranslationY = view.translationY
view.viewTreeObserver.addOnDrawListener {
  if (previousTranslationX != view.translationX || 
      previousTranslationY != view.translationY) {
    previousTranslationX = view.translationX
    previousTranslationY = view.translationY

    dispatchViewTranslationUpdated(view)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply register a callback to be invoked when the view tree is about to be drawn.

**Note:** This listener *almost* called every time the view is drawn!

```
public class MyView extends View {
    private float oldScaleX;
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        getViewTreeObserver().addOnDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDraw() {
                // Many things can invoke this method! We don't know why view going 
                // to be redrawn, So we must determine the cause ourselves.
                float newScaleX=getScaleX();
                if (oldScaleX!=newScaleX) {
                        scaleXUpdated();
                        oldScaleX=newScaleX;
                    }

            }
        });

    }


    private void scaleXUpdated() {
        Log.e(TAG,"scaleX updated "+getScaleX);
    }

}
```